# How remove comments with sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have file like this

```
<IfModule mod_unixd.c>
    # Run as a unique, less privileged user for security reasons.
    # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
    # Default: User #-1, Group #-1
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_unixd.html
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege
    User www-data #
    Group www-data
</IfModule>
```

I use command for removing comments but it doesn't remove comments, what's wrong?

```
 sed -e '/^[\s]*#/d' test.conf'
```

[Regexp in online](https://regex101.com/r/iMQyaw/1)

Output must be

```
<IfModule mod_unixd.c>
    User www-data #
    Group www-data
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2):

> Output must be

Looks like you want to remove lines beginning with a `#` (after zero or more whitespaces) and you don't want to remove comments which begins after the end of non-comment statements (like `User www-data #`)

Try this:

```
sed -e '/^\s*#/d' test.conf
```

Or this:

```
sed -e '/^[ \t]*#/d' test.conf
```

This regex will match lines beginning with 0 or more spaces or tabs (in any order), followed by a hash sign.

GNU sed also supports symbolic names:

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*/d'
```

Which includes all whitespace characters, including the funny unicode foreign language ones. That's less portable, however.

**EDIT:**

`sed --version` on my system returns:

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
Packaged by Debian
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove any line beginning with whitespace followed by `#`, you can use

```
sed -e '/^\W*#/d' test.conf
```

This means the pattern matches

- from the beginning of the line
- allows only whitespace characters
- followed by `#`
- anything after that is ignored

Comment: But it deletes with `User www-data #`

Comment: @Vitalii Yes, that's right. I wasn't aware of the /d - thank you. I edited it.

Comment: @Vitalii could you accept the answer if it helped you?